# Kendo-Dropdown Angular Console Error: "Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-angular-ui

I am using kendo dropdown with label in my angular application. But I am getting below issue on browser console.

[image]

I can see the same issue in the kendo demo web site as well. Please check below URL. Is there any way to fix this issue.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/examples/dropdownlist/basic_usage/?theme=material-main&themeVersion=6.4.0